# I wish to move this patch in my 3D scatter plot either by using a mouse or slider. But it is very slow. Suggest me a better way to do it

Tags: plotly-dash, ipywidgets

I have a 3D scatter plot of approximately 15000 data points. I also have a spherical patch in the plot. I wish to move this patch in my 3D scatter plot either by using a mouse or slider. Then I wish to record the data points that are enclosed by the sphere. How to perform this?

I have the program as shown below. The patch moves as I move the slider but the image update only after few seconds as if it refreshes the page. So I cannot see a real-time update of my scatter plot as I move the slider. This is the main problem. The next is to record the co-ordinates of the data points enclosed by the spherical patch. I'm figuring out on how to implement this. Meanwhile, let me know if you have a quick solution to it.

```
``
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed,interact_manual
    import ipywidgets as widgets
    from IPython.display import display


    #plotting the scatter plot

    scatter = go.Scatter3d(x = projected_spectrum2[0], 
                                                y = projected_spectrum2[1],
                                                z = projected_spectrum2[2],
                                                mode ='markers', 
                                                marker = dict (
                                                    size =2, color = projected_spectrum2[2], 
                                                    colorscale = 'hsv', opacity  =0.5,     colorbar=dict(title="Principal component 3")))

    #plotting spherical patch

    radius = 20
    center = (projected_spectrum2.max()-projected_spectrum2.min())/2 
    phi = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 20)#phi
    theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 20)#theta
    theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)


    x_sphere = center [0] + radius * np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta))#np.outer is a cross product
    y_sphere = center [1] + radius * np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
    z_sphere = center [2] + radius * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
    patch = go.Surface(x = x_sphere, y = y_sphere, z = z_sphere, opacity =0.1, showscale= False,     surfacecolor = np.full((400,400), 200))

    scatter_plot = go.Figure ( data = [patch, scatter])

    scatter_plot.update_layout(scene = dict(
                        xaxis_title='Principal Component 1',
                        yaxis_title='Principal Component 2',
                        zaxis_title='Principal Component 3'))


    def update_patch(x_shift, y_shift, z_shift):
        scatter_plot.data[0].x = x_sphere + x_shift
        scatter_plot.data[0].y = y_sphere + y_shift
        scatter_plot.data[0].z = z_sphere + z_shift
        return scatter_plot
    x_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=670, step=10, value=30, description='X Shift')
    y_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=670, step=10, value=23, description='Y Shift')
    z_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=670, step=10, value=543, description='Z Shift')

    interact(update_patch, x_shift=x_slider, y_shift=y_slider, z_shift=z_slider)
    scatter_plot.show()
```

``